# Adding specific 'badging' to a sku if it is on offer

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

I have a list of products that need a badge adding if they are found on a list/category page. I have this so far but it's adding badges to every sku and not the ones specified.

The code I have so far is:

```
  const $discountedProducts = options.state.get('$discountedProducts')

  const elibigleSKUs = [
    '5981BZ501', 'CBMV03300', 'PCMC03300', 'PCMC46800', 'PCMS03300', 
    'PCMS46800', 'PCMV03300', 'PCMV46800', 'PKMC03300', 'PKMC46800', 
    'PKMS46800', 'PKMV03300', 'PKMV46800', 'RACOU4800', 'RAFRX6600',
    'RAJUC6000', 'RALWC6001', 'RALWC6002', 'RAMC03300', 'RAMC46800',
    'RAMS03300', 'RAMS46800', 'RAMV03300', 'RCMC46800', 'RCMS03300',
    'RCMS46800', 'RCMV03300', 'RCMV46800', 'SEBCBH700', 'SECOU4800',
    'SEFRX6600', 'SEJUC6000', 'SELWC6000', 'SEMC03300', 'SEMC46800',
    'SEMS03300', 'SEMS46800', 'SEMV03300', 'SEMV46800', 'SEOS65100',
    'SEOX02702', 'SEOX02704', 'STMC03300', 'STMC46800', 'STMS03300',
    'STMS46800', 'STMV03300', 'STMV46800', 'SWCOU4800', 'SEATAY600',
    'SEAT65100', 'RAAT65100', 'PKMS03300', 'RAATAY600'
  ]

  const targets = [
    '.productCard_mediaContainer'
  ]

  poller(targets, ($products) => {
    const $discountedProducts = $products.filter(function () {
      const $this = $(this)
      const $link = $this.find('.productCard_mediaContainer > a')
      const currentSku = String($link.data('code')).toUpperCase()

      if (elibigleSKUs.indexOf(currentSku) >= -1) {
        return true
      }
        return false
    })

    if ($discountedProducts.length) {
      $('.productCard_mediaContainer').append('<div class="t028-percent-off productCard_promoLine"><span class="discount"><strong>10%</strong> discount applied</span></div>').addClass('t028');
    }
  })
```

So it targets a container and attempts to inject the badge per sku. Apologise if this is not perfect but I am more Design/UX than Dev. Any help would be much appreciated. I can add more info if this is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding `console.log()` statements in your poller function to see what you're getting. You could do something like this:

```
if (elibigleSKUs.indexOf(currentSku) >= -1) {
   console.log("This SKU is eligible " + currentSku);
   return true
 }

console.log("This SKU is NOT eligible " + currentSku);
return false
```

This should give you a place to start.

Comment: Thanks, so this has helped. The sku is showing eligible but currentSku is showing as undefined. I'll have a look at why it doesn't seem to be recognising the currentSku

Comment: Also I just noticed you wrote ">= -1" so if it doesn't find the SKU it will still enter that if block. I'm thinking if it's not found in the array you don't want that behavior so I would change it to just be "> -1" or just "!= -1"

Comment: If it's showing undefined for currentSku you might want to look at this line "const currentSku = String($link.data('code')).toUpperCase()"